# Is there a Resharper command to find where a variable is being set?

Tags: resharper

When I am debugging code, if I have to find where a variable is being set, I do a text search for that variable. If there was a resharper command to go to the line of code where the variable is being set, that would save me a lot of time. Does anyone know if resharper provides  this functionality?

Comment: wait do you mean C# or Resharper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aside from `Find usages` you can also right click and choose `Inspect -> Value origin`. It only shows places where value is written, and allows you to further expand them, showing where did the assigned value come from.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the variable name, and choose `Find Usages`. In the window that pops, you should be able to see how its used. There are various filtering options in the toolbar.

Comment: Or hit Shift+F12 when cursor is over variable/type